# Work on a Wordpress site in Plesk before DNS is pointed

Tags: wordpress, plesk

I've installed Wordpress on a 'subscription' in Plesk (latest version) on my server. The domain related to the subscription is not currently pointed to my server. However, I'd like to work on the Wordpress admin area before I point the domain.

Can this be done? At the moment if I use the 'login' button on the domain in Plesk it redirects me to the actual domain. Which as I say isn't currently pointed so gives me an error.

Can I access the website via the server and the directory folder of the site?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can update your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to map the domain to the IP address of your server.

If the domain were `example.com` and the IP address of your server was `111.111.111.111` you would just need to add the line:

```
111.111.111.111 example.com
```

You can find where your hosts file is located [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system).